# Prove that $p^n-1$ is the unique element of $\mathbb{Z}_{p^n}^*$ with order 2

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-number-theory

I am currently working with Contemporary Abstract Algebra, Joseph A. Gallian (10th edition).
In an very early chapter (even before the Lagrange's Theorem is introduced), I was asked to prove this following statement (Ch3 Q84):

> If p is an odd prime and n is a positive integer, prove that $p^n-1$ is the unique element in $U(p^n)$ of order 2.

(In this textbook, $U(n)=\mathbb{Z}_n^*$)
I could prove the statement for $n=1$, but couldn't generalize further. Here's my proof:

> Since $(p-1)^2=p^2-2p+1\equiv1$ (mod p), $|p-1|=2$
> Suppose there exists some a $\in\mathbb{Z}_p^*\setminus\{1,p-1\}$ such that $|a|=2$, then
> $$(p-1)^2-a^2=kp$$ for some positive integer k,
> i.e. $(p-1-a)(a+p-1)=kp$.
> $1\leq p-1-a \leq p-1$ and $1\leq a-1 \leq p-1$ follow from the assumption, thus $p-1-a,\ a-1 \in\mathbb{Z}_p^*$. 
> The product $(p-1-a)(a+p-1)$ modulo p would give an element in $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ by the closeness of $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ under the multiplication operation.
> However, the equality above implies that $(p-1-a)(a+p-1)$ is an integer multiple of $p$, which can't be an element of $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$. A contradiction.

A bit of searching online points me towards using the Fermat's Little Theorem,
but I prefer not using it, since this results from Lagrange's Theorem. Is there a somewhat elementary solution to this problem?

Comment: I think this is doable using some simple facts about prime numbers. Suppose $x^2 = 1 \pmod{p^n}$. Then $p^n \mid (x + 1)(x - 1)$. What you want to show is that $p^n$ divides at least one of $x + 1$ and $x - 1$. Suppose not - then $p$ must divide both $x - 1$ and $x + 1$, so $p$ divides their difference, which is $2$. So $p$ is not an odd prime.

Comment: What is your $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$?

Comment: @MathFail [The multiplicative group of integers modulo n](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n)